# Como popular vários select

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql-server, select

Consegui fazer com que o segundo select (jogador) carregue automaticamente de acordo com o primeiro selecionado (torneio). Eu preciso fazer com que o terceiro  (jogo) carregue de acordo com o segundo. 
No meu caso, tenho uma equipe, que carrega uma lista de jogadores que participam (ou não) de jogos em determinadas datas. Preciso escolher o jogador e carregar no terceiro select a lista de datas de jogos que ele participou. Se ele não participou de nenhum, solta uma msg e deu. Eu implementei até o código de acordo como carregou no primeiro select, mas o terceiro select (torneio) some da tela quando seleciono o segundo (jogador). Alguma ideia?

form dentro da página:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <select name="ID_torneio" id="ID_torneio">
         <option value="">Escolha o torneio</option>
         <?php
             $Sql_Query = "SELECT * FROM dbo.Torneios ORDER BY nomeTorneio";
             $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn,$Sql_Query);                     
             while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                 echo "'<option value=".$row['ID_torneio'].">".$row['nomeTorneio']."</option>";    
               } 
         ?>
    </select>

    <span class="carregando">Sem resultados</span>
    <select name="ID_atleta" id="ID_atleta">
         <option value="">Escolha o atleta</option>
    </select>

    <select name="ID_jogo" id="ID_jogo">
         <option value="">Escolha o jogo</option>                                        
    </select>
</form>
```

Script do jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
       $('#ID_atleta').change(function(){
            if( $(this).val() ) {
                $('#ID_jogo').hide();
                $('.carregando').show();
                $.getJSON('select_jogo_por_atleta_escolhido.php?search=',{ID_atleta: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                    var options = '<option value="">Escolha o jogo</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                        options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].nome_jogo + '</option>';    
                    }    
                    $('#ID_jogo').html(options).show();
                    $('.carregando').hide();
                });
            } else {
                $('#ID_jogo').html('<option value="">Escolha o jogo</option>');
            }
       });
    });
</script>
```

Código PHP da busca e montagem do Json:

```
<?php   
    include_once("conexao.php");

    $ID_atleta = $_REQUEST['ID_atleta'];

    $r1 = "SELECT dataJogo FROM dbo.Table WHERE atleta = $ID_atleta AND passeErrado>0 AND chuteAgol>0 AND perdida>0 AND interceptacao>0 ORDER BY dataJogo DESC";
    $stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn,$r1);       
    while( $rowData = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $nomes_atletas_json[] = array(          
                    'id'    => $row_sub_cat['dataJogo'],
                    'data_jogo' => utf8_encode($row_sub_cat['dataJogo']),
        );
    }
    echo(json_encode($nomes_atletas_json));
?>
```

Retorno do banco, onde estão os dados de data de jogos por jogador:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado antes de selecionar o jogador
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Select após selecionar o jogador: está sumindo o select do jogo (traz a data)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi. Ele sempre usa o name do select anterior como request no codigo PHP que vai popular o próximo select. No primeiro select ele usa o PHP direto. No segundo select, ele pega pelo primeiro codigo javascript mais abaixo. No terceiro select, ele pego pelo segundo javascript abaixo.

```
                        <select name="ID_torneio" id="ID_torneio">
                             <option value="">Escolha o torneio</option>
                             <?php
                                  $Sql_Query = "SELECT * FROM torneios ORDER BY nomeTorneio";
                                  $stmt = mysqli_query($conn, $Sql_Query);
                                  if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$Sql_Query))
                                  {
                                       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                       {
                                            echo "<option value=".$row['ID_torneio'].">".$row['nomeTorneio']."</option>"; 
                                       }
                                  }
                             ?>
                        </select>

                        <span class="carregando">Sem resultados</span>
                        <select name="ID_atleta" id="ID_atleta">
                             <option value="">Escolha o atleta</option>
                        </select>
                         <span class="carregando">Sem resultados</span>
                        <select name="ID_jogo" id="ID_jogo">
                             <option value="">Escolha o jogo</option>                                        
                        </select>




   //Seleciona o torneio e busca os atletas cadastrados nele        

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
          </script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){
               $('#ID_torneio').change(function(){
                    if( $(this).val() ) {
                         $('#ID_atleta').hide();
                         $('.carregando').show();
                         $.getJSON('select_atletas_por_torneio_escolhido.php?search=',{ID_torneio: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                              var options = '<option value="">Escolha o atleta</option>';

                              for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                                   options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].nome_atleta + '</option>';
                              }    
                              $('#ID_atleta').html(options).show();
                              $('.carregando').hide();
                         });
                    } else {
                         $('#ID_atleta').html('<option value="">– Escolha o atleta –</option>');
                    }
               });
          });
          </script>


        //Seleciona o atleta e busca todos o jogos que ele teve alguma ação registrada, mínima que seja  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
          </script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){
               $('#ID_atleta').change(function(){
                    if( $(this).val() ) {
                         $('#ID_jogo').hide();
                         $('.carregando').show();
                         $.getJSON('select_jogo_por_atleta_escolhido.php?search=',{ID_atleta: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
                              var options = '<option value="">Escolha o jogo</option>';
                              for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
                                   options += '<option value="' + j[i].id + '">' + j[i].dataJogo + '</option>';

                              }    
                              $('#ID_jogo').html(options).show();
                              $('.carregando').hide();
                         });
                    } else {
                         $('#ID_jogo').html('<option value="">Escolha o jogo</option>');
                    }
               });
          });
          </script>
```

PHP (um deles)

```
<?php   
    include_once("conexao.php");

    $ID_atleta = $_REQUEST['ID_atleta'];
    //$ID_atleta = "Bage";

    $sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT dataJogo FROM eventos WHERE atleta='$ID_atleta' AND passeErrado>'0' AND chuteAgol>'0' AND perdida>'0' AND interceptacao>'0'";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1)) {
        while ($row_sub_cat = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $sub_categorias_post[] = array(         
                'id'    => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_sub_cat['dataJogo'])),
                'dataJogo' => date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row_sub_cat['dataJogo'])),
            );
        }
    }
    echo(json_encode($sub_categorias_post));
?>
```